# Delphi: OleVariant and Generics

Tags: delphi, generics

Consider the following code extract:

```
type
  MyIntf = interface
    procedure Work(param: OleVariant);
  end;

  MyClass<T> = class
    procedure MyWork(param: T);
  end;

var
  intf: MyIntf;

procedure MyClass<T>.MyWork(param: T);
begin
  //compiler error: E2010 Incompatible types: 'OleVariant' and 'T'
  intf.Work(param);
end;
```

This fails to compile with the error message as indicated above. How could I call the `Work` function from my generic class?

Comment: Why oh why is this fine question getting close votes? Are the voters even looking at what they are voting on?

Comment: Not to worry, we can always reopen :-)

Comment: @Johan We should not have to. These review queues at SO are just stupid.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I vote to close this question, before your make the edit. The original question was not clear and also does not post real code.

Comment: @RRUZ Yes I understand. But I fixed the Q when there were only two close votes. It's the blind ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code fails to compile because the compiler cannot guarantee at compile time of the generic class that there is a possible conversion to all conceivable `T`.

When faced with

```
intf.Work(param);
```

in the generic method the compiler needs to know how to convert `param` to `OleVariant`. And it cannot do so. This is one of the limitations of generics in comparison with templates.

---

The easiest solution for you is to do the conversion at runtime with help from `TValue` from the `Rtti` unit.

```
procedure MyClass<T>.MyWork(param: T);
begin
  intf.Work(TValue.From<T>(param).AsVariant);
end;
```

And here's a sample test program to demonstrate that `TValue` does the job:

```
program SO15113162;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Rtti;

procedure Work(param: OleVariant);
begin
  Writeln(param);
end;

type
  MyClass<T> = class
    class procedure MyWork(param: T);
  end;

class procedure MyClass<T>.MyWork(param: T);
begin
  Work(TValue.From<T>(param).AsVariant);
end;

begin
  MyClass<Double>.MyWork(2.4);
  MyClass<string>.MyWork('hello');
  MyClass<Integer>.MyWork(-666);
  Readln;
end.
```

**Output**

```
2.4
hello
-666
```